# Proper way to declare more than one EXSLT extension in an XSLT stylesheet

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, exslt

What is the proper way to declare more that one EXSLT extension in a single XSLT stylesheet?

And more importantly what is the purpose of `xmlns:*="http://exslt.org/*"`?

The [documentation](http://exslt.org/howto.html) says:

> You can use the extension-element-prefixes attribute to prevent the extension namespaces from being output in the result tree.

Is it just so as to not have `xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times` displayed in the root node of the output document? and if so why is it important?

With the following stylesheet I get the error:

`lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Attribute extension-element-prefixes redefined, line 7, column 40`

I'm using XSLT 1.0 with the [lxml](http://lxml.de/) processor.

**XML Input**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl" version="1.0"?>
<item>test</item>
```

**XSLT 1.0 Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet
      version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
      xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
      extension-element-prefixes="str"
      extension-element-prefixes="date">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
      <xsl:value-of
        select="str:padding(2 - string-length(date:month-in-year()), 0)"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="date:month-in-year()"/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML Output**

```
<html xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times">
  <body>05</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to populate the `xsl:extension-element-prefixes` attribute with a whitespace-separated list of the declared namespace prefixes.  In your example, that would be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
extension-element-prefixes="str date">
```

---

> And more importantly what is the purpose of
>   `xmlns:*="http://exslt.org/*"`?

It's a namespace declaration that binds the prefix to a namespace URI. The prefix can be anything you want - it is the namespace URI that tells the processor that the element is in a namespace that belongs to a supported extension.

This has nothing to do with preventing the declaration from appearing in the output. That is accomplished by using either an `extension-element-prefixes` or `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute. Why is this important? It may be important if the namespace declaration is not part of the target schema.